# How to like a website from my Android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have an application that show to the user articles from news feeds.
I want to add Facebook like mechanism, that when the user push the like button,
his Facebook account will show that he is like this article.

So, I downloaded the Facebook sdk, and worked with the open graph example.
The problem is that I can't find any good example of how to to this.

I understand that I have action types, and object types. I added action type of `me/og.likes` and now I need to send the url of the selected article.

What I do so far is:

I have this lines, what they do is only add which type of action my application can handle.

this is working fine.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("object", "http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791");

Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/og.likes",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
// handle the response
```

Now I want to send the actual url of the selected article, do I need to use some kind of outside url of an object or I can build object in my application and send it?

Any help would be great,

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When creating an action you must be sure that facebook robot can see the URL and correct meta tags. You can debug your page on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). So in your case as I understand facebook can't visit your application and therefore can't determine meta tags in your app. So the solution I can offer is creating a web page which will generate meta tags depending on the `$_GET[]` parameter. You can pass an article ID and generate meta tags for that ID.

Comment: Do I have to use some kind of web page? I can't create local object and send it? I have the Facebook example about it, and they uses a web page, it is working in that way, but I want to do it without the web page...

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will continue to investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is library which completely solve this issue ([project page](http://blog.shamanland.com/p/facebook-like-button.html)):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:facebook-like-button:0.1.8'
}
```

The simplest way to add like button:

```
<com.shamanland.facebook.likebutton.FacebookLikeButton
    style="@style/Widget.FacebookLikeButton"
    app:pageUrl="http://url.to.like/page.html"
    app:pageTitle="Title of page"
    app:pageText="Short description of page"
    app:pagePictureUrl="http://url.to.like/picture.jpg"
    />
```

This view will be drawn in your layout: [image]

After clicking on it you will see the dialog with official Facebook 'Like' plugin.

Read [more details](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/06/facebook-like-button-for-android.html).

[image]